# MongoDB store a order with duplicate _id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I've a orders collection where if the user orders a service it will store all the information of the order. Right now I've 3 services available in my application . For testing with one email address I ordered all 3 services . Then with another email address I tried to order a same service it will show this error [image]

How Can I store this order in my DB ?

My backend Code

```
app.post("/addOrder", (req, res) => {
    const newOrder = req.body;
    console.log("Order", newOrder);
    ordersCollection.insertOne(newOrder).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.insertedCount);
      res.send({ count: result.insertedCount });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad . It was a problem from Client Side. I didn't notice the Id which was being saved in Database wasn't created by the Mongo DB rather it was me who was sending the product id.